# I want to get the API data into my Text element ~ React Native

Tags: react-native

I have done an API call and got the data into a variable.
But now I want to show them in a TEXT element.
My Data from API
[image: API DATA]

My Code

```
function RenderServiceTicket(){
    return ( 
    <SafeAreaView>
     <View>
     <Text>{data.createdAt}</Text>
     </View>
     </SafeAreaView>
)}
```

I want to get the ***"createdAt": "2021-08-06 13:27:55",***

[image]

API Call code

```
const  onRefresh = React.useCallback(async() => {
    setServiceTData([]);
    const deviceId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@device_ID')
    const sessionId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@session_Id')
    console.log('device ID: ',deviceId, 'session IDs: ', sessionId)
      setRefreshing(true);        
        (async () => {
        try{
        const ServiceTicketData = await fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/serviceTicket`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'apiKey': 'asdkhjfgsed34e',
                'deviceId': deviceId,
                'sessionId': sessionId
    
            },
        })
        const STData = await ServiceTicketData.json();
        console.log("ST Data",STData);
        setServiceTData(STData.data);
        setRefreshing(false)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })()
        
    }, [refreshing]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your code, I would suggest to try something like that :

```
const [serviceTData, setServiceTData] = React.useState([]);

const onRefresh = React.useCallback(async() => {
    
  const deviceId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@device_ID');
  const sessionId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@session_Id');
  console.log('device ID: ',deviceId, 'session IDs: ', sessionId);
  setRefreshing(true);        
  (async () => {
    try{
      const ServiceTicketData = await fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/serviceTicket`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'apiKey': 'asdkhjfgsed34e',
          'deviceId': deviceId,
          'sessionId': sessionId
    
        },
      });
      const STData = await ServiceTicketData.json();
      console.log('ST Data',STData);
      setServiceTData(STData.data);
      setRefreshing(false);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })();
        
}, [refreshing]);

const RenderServiceTicket = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={{height: '50%', width: '50%'}}>
        {serviceTData.length > 0 && <Text>{serviceTData.createdAt}</Text>} // at this point, you should get a black text, add some style
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Beside I would apply some style to the text and some size to the container in order for the element to be displayed.

If it still does not work, then you should review the way you handle your async functions.